# Confused where to ask question!

Tags: support, scope

There are A LOT OF forums for asking our questions about computers!  Sometimes I really get confused where to ask to get the best answer in the shortest time.

For example, I have a question about IPV6.  I don't know which is the best forum:

- Superuser?
- Server fault?

then I'll find a similar question in Stackoverflow with a good answer (better than mine!)  I thought Stackoverflow is for programming problems.

Comment: I rolled back your question to my edit because it's easier to read as well as it leave the word "forum" in there which is essential to answers being given.

Comment: @Hanna - Superuser isn't a forum. A question about IPv6 belongs on Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound not all IPv6 question belong on SuperUser.

Comment: @KronoS - I took a wild guess and determined that the type of question Hanna would have likely would be on topic for Superuser.  I just took made a general statement.

Answer (score 7):

First off this isn't a forum.  It's a Questions/Answers community where individuals have questions and experts vote on and answer those questions.  Forums have a reputation of pretty much allowing just about anything, and often times turn into long discussions.  Stack Exchange isn't a community for conversation, but rather a community for problem solving.

As far as where to ask a question, I highly recommend looking at the FAQ of the sites that you think might be a good fit.  Most established sites have really solid FAQ's that describe what is and what isn't on-topic for the SE site.

Comment: You're right.Questions/Answers community!There were a lot of questions about "Which forum to ask..." so I thought forum is right.Sry

Comment: No need to apologize.  It's a very different approach than what the rest of the internet world is used too.  It's better, but very different and therefore can be a bit confusing at first to first timers here :)

Comment: To add on to what Kronos said, part of the purpose of Stack Exchange is to develop expert communities for _specific_ subject areas. This is why you see so many similar but different sites. For example, while SF, SO, and SU are all about "computers" and can have some overlap in topic, they're each about very different, specific topics within "computers": SO for programming, SF for systems administration and more large-IT-organization type questions, and SU for more general computing questions.

Comment: It seems Stackoverflow is the most popular community in stackexchange so the chance of getting good answers is higher there.Even not much related ones!Anyway I like Superuser so much more:)

Comment: @Hanna - If you ask all your questions on Stackoverflow and they are not topic eventually you won't be able to ask any questions ( even on topic questsions ) because you will be prevented from asking questions.  Just because Stackoverflow is more popular doesn't mean the others are not popular and you won't recieve the correct answer on them.